# After Converting GMT time date not in 24hour format android code

Tags: android, date

I was trying to converted user inputed date in GMT time, user inputed date in 24hour format, when i convert in GMT time it show 12 hour problem, How can i get 24 hour formated GMT time

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");


    String s = starttDatePicker.getYear() + "-"
        + (starttDatePicker.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
        + starttDatePicker.getDayOfMonth() + " "
        + starttimepicer.getCurrentHour() + ":"
        + starttimepicer.getCurrentMinute() + ":" + "00";

Date parsed = null;

try {
    parsed = format1.parse(s);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
format1.setTimeZone(tz);

posttime = format1.format(parsed);
```

Comment: I didn't get you, `starttDatePicker` is giving you a 24 hours format and you want it get converted to 12 hours GMT, is that right?

Comment: i want to convert in 24 hours GMT time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Just to clarify the documentation for formatting date/times mentions that hh is 12 hour time while HH is 24 hour time.

Comment: thank you so much, its fix, guess i need to study more about time format, i tried with aa after :ss thaught that indicate AM PM

Comment: p or pp is the standard for am/pm

Answer (score 1):

`hh` is for 12 hrs format and
`HH` is for 24 hrs format